# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined while setting title in "this"

Tags: javascript

I have an element

`<td onmouseover="show('VersionToolTip',0,0,this)" onmouseout="startTimer(this)" title="">Version</td>`

javascript

```js
function show(sDest, itop, ileft, s) { 

 if(navigator.appVersion.toUpperCase().indexOf("CHROME") !== -1){
  s.title = document.getElementById(sDest);
 }

}
```

when i hover(tool tip) the `version`  i get `objectHTML[TableElement]` but i expect the value which is in `document.getElementById(sDest)`

when i debug i get see the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined while setting title in "this"

Comment: What do you mean by "_i expect the value_"? According to the `objectHTML[TableElement]` it seems that you are selecting a table. What do you expect to show of the table?

Comment: Hi Ivar, I expect the string value which is derived from `document.getElementById(sDest);` . when i hover over the `version` word

Comment: `document.getElementById(sDest);` returns the DOM element that you select, not a string. It is a holder for all attributes, child elements, text, etc. It's unclear to me what string you are talking about.

Comment: Also [I'm not able to reproduce that error](https://jsfiddle.net/bx4pywer/) with your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me. Based on Both @ShivRatna and @Ivar 's input

```js
if( navigator.appVersion.toUpperCase().indexOf("CHROME") !== -1){
  
  var dest = document.getElementById(sDest);
  console.log(dest.innerText);
  s.title = (dest.innerText);
  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setAttribute` to set the title and `innerText` to get the text:-

```
function show(sDest, itop, ileft, s) {  

    if(navigator.appVersion.toUpperCase().indexOf("CHROME") !== -1){
        s.setAttribute('title', document.getElementById(sDest).innerText);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined` error actually

Comment: I have created a working fiddle for you. Please have a look. https://jsfiddle.net/kumarshivratn/mf3w89e4/13/

Comment: You don't need `setAttribute` here. `.title` works fine.

Comment: Thank you @ShivratnaKumar and Ivar